# Program that takes a string with multiple words and capitalizes the first letter of each word (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, string

I tried making **a program that takes a string with multiple words and capitilizes the first letter of each word.**

---

*The following program was what I ended up with:*

```
string = input('Enter line:')
length = len(string)
string2 = ''
for i in range(0, length):
    if i == 0:
        string2 += string[0].upper()
        continue
    elif string[i] == ' ':
        string2 += string[i]
        string2 += string[i+1].upper()
        continue
    elif string[i] != ' ':
        if string2[i].upper() is True:  # I feel like there is something wrong with this line
            continue
        else:
            string2 += string[i]
print(string2)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter line:hey my
Hey Mmy
```

What is wrong with my program? Can you just point out the error so that I can try fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip the next 2 characters once you hit a space and handle the word-break. This is simpler with a while-loop.

```
while i < len(string):
    if i == 0:
        string2 += string[0].upper()
        i += 1
        continue
    elif string[i] == ' ':
        string2 += string[i]
        string2 += string[i+1].upper()
        i += 2
        continue
    elif string[i] != ' ':
        string2 += string[i]
        i += 1
print(string2)
```

However there is a much shorter, much more pythonic way to achieve the same result:

```
string = 'hey my'

retval = ' '.join(x.title() for x in string.split())

print(retval)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 3 lines.

```py
string = input('Enter line:')
strings = map(lambda x: x.capitalize(), string.split())
print(' '.join(strings))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str=input("enter sentence:")
x=""
y=str.split()
for i in y:
    x+=i.capitalize()+ " "
print("resultant string:",x)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

See.. in that line just change it as string[i] instread of string2[i]